# Create MonoGame.Framework.iOS.dll

Tags: ios, dll, monogame

I have the known landscape problem with iOS 8 and MonoGame 3.2. I have read that if I download the newest code from github this will fix the problem. My issue is that I can't seem to build a working dll from what I have downloaded from github.

Maybe I'm a little noob but earlier there was a Xamarin solution I opened, build and then I located the dlls I needed in the BIN folder. But this is not the case when I downloaded the zip from github. Is there someone who can maybe explain to me how I do this? Would really mean the world to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the latest built DLLs at:
http://teamcity.monogame.net/viewType.html?buildTypeId=MonoGame_DevelopMac

Just open the latest build and navigate to "Artifacts" tab.